# PDO update query runs changes no rows. No errors

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I'm running a PDO update working, and for some reason it won't update the table...

```
$business_id = 9874128;
$hidden = 1;
$query = "UPDATE business_property_overrides SET hidden=? WHERE business_id=?";

try {
      $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
      $stmt->execute(array($business_id, $hidden));
}
```

For some reason this won't update, even though I get no errors. The existing tables schema looks like this, and the data is:

There is an existing data set with business_id = 9874128 and hidden set to 0, but it won't update when I run the above code.

```
CREATE TABLE `business_property_overrides` (
  `business_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `apt_type` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `apt_num` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `street_address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hours` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `openhours` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` point DEFAULT NULL,
  `yelp` varchar(512) DEFAULT '0',
  `twitter` varchar(512) DEFAULT '0',
  `hidden` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `merged` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `closed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `business_id` (`business_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9874134 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: You've interchange the values `$stmt->execute(array($business_id, $hidden));` it should be `$stmt->execute(array($hidden,$business_id));`

Answer (score 0):

The `hidden` is `TINYINT` `1 characters long`, you are assigning it `business_id` which is `7 characters long`, that is the error.

Change

```
$stmt->execute(array($business_id, $hidden));
```

To:

```
$stmt->execute(array($hidden,$business_id))
```

Answer (score 0):

As I've already commented over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32859368/pdo-update-query-runs-changes-no-rows-no-errors#comment53551802_32859368), or you can simply use the placeholders of taking no care about the occurence like as

```
$query = "UPDATE business_property_overrides SET hidden = :hidden WHERE business_id = :business_id";

try {
      $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
      $stmt->execute(array(":business_id" => $business_id, ":hidden" => $hidden));
}
```